# Send form values to an email

Tags: playframework

How do I forward the user-entered values in a form(ie: their name, e-mail, and their message) to a dedicated e-mail inbox through play frsamework 1.2.5?

Answer (score 0):

import `play.libs.Mail` and try this: (this is for 1.2.4, but it should work)

```
SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setFrom("sender@zenexity.fr");
email.addTo("recipient@zenexity.fr");
email.setSubject("subject");
email.setMsg("Message");
Mail.send(email);
```

By default, in DEV mode, the e-mail will be printed to the console, while in PROD mode it will be sent to the actual SMTP server. You can change the default behaviour in DEV mode by commenting the following line:

`# Default is to use a mock Mailer

mail.smtp=mock`

here is the SMTP Configuration:

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=yourGmailLogin
mail.smtp.pass=yourGmailPassword
mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

which should reside in `application.conf`, If i remember right

Comment: I'm a newbie. Can you help me with the controller code too? It will help me a lot.

Comment: @Khekhekhe, sure. what is the problem?